# node - How to deploy script to Google Cloud functions

Tags: node.js, deployment, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot

I need to deploy a node script to cloud functions. I've created a new function and pasted the code inside the editor, all the necessary dependencies are listed into the `package.json` and I've also created an `.env` file that will hold some informations.

The script initially was made to be executed from cli but now that I need to deploy it I'm not sure if it will work, it's a telegram bot script and I don't know if I need to create any action to be sure that it will be executed when the bot receive a commend from the users.

Anyone with more experience on gcloud can explain to me if my deployment is made correctly?Do I need to use cloud shell or I can just copy/paste my code into a new function and it will run?

This is the code I have at the moment, but it will be not executed in cloud functions

```js
const process = require('process');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const bot = new TelegramBot(process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN, { polling: true });
const webHookURL = 'https://example.com/'

let baseURL = 'https://example.com/events.php';
let chatID;
let username;
let eventsList = [];

puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
}).then(  async (browser) => {

    const page = await browser.newPage()
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()

    await page.goto(baseURL, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0'  
    })

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 607 })

    await page.waitForSelector('.sc-VigVT > #qc-cmp2-ui > .qc-cmp2-footer > .qc-cmp2-summary-buttons > .ljEJIv')
    await page.click('.sc-VigVT > #qc-cmp2-ui > .qc-cmp2-footer > .qc-cmp2-summary-buttons > .ljEJIv')

    await navigationPromise

    await page.waitForSelector('.container > .row > .results-item > .kode_ticket_wraper > .container')

    await navigationPromise

    await page.waitForSelector('.container > .kode_ticket_list > li')

    eventsList = await page.$$eval('ul.kode_ticket_list > li', el => {
        return el.map( e => {
            let url = e.querySelector('.ticket_btn > a').getAttribute('href') 
            return {
                type: e.querySelector('.kode_ticket_text > h6').innerHTML,
                time: e.querySelector('.kode_ticket_text > p').innerHTML,
                url: url,
                name: new URL(url).pathname.split('-').join(' ').slice(6)
            }
        })
    })
    await browser.close()
})

// I need to set the webhhok, I've seen the documentations of the library I'm using but seems not working 
bot.setWebHook(`${webHookURL}/bot${process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}`)

bot.onText(/\/dirette/, (msg, match) => {
    username = msg.chat.first_name
    chatID = msg.chat.id

    let response = `Hi ${username}! Here is a list of today live events:\n\n`
    eventsList.map( item => {
        response += `<b>${item.type}</b>\n`
        response += `<b>${item.time}</b>\n`
        response += `<a href='${item.url}'>${item.name.toUpperCase()}</a>\n\n`
    })
    bot.sendMessage(chatID, response, { parse_mode: 'HTML', disable_web_page_preview: true })
})
```

Comment: Could you explain why exactly you want to use Cloud Functions? In this case I would recommend using App Engine as Cloud Functions are meant to be single-purpose pieces of code. Read more about GAE [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app)

Comment: @mdobrucki I've thought that it's the best way to run my bot instance that is including a puppeteer instance. Anyway I need to test the App engine to achive my scope

Comment: @mdobrucki tested the app engine, I'm able to deploy the node script of my telegram bot but it will not work. Maybe I need to set a webhook or something similar?

Comment: Can you share more details in the post? Any errors you are getting? Your `app.yaml` manifest.